# Heroku breaks when devise attempts to send confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, web-hosting

```
2011-10-24T05:54:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 69.136.182.141 at 2011-10-23 22:54:00 -0700
2011-10-24T05:54:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2011-10-24T05:54:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ts2MkJf472PHTEcKjdD3P5YjBr/sWX3jTDZKjPZNYj0=", "user"=>{"username"=>"DerNalia", "email"=>"[not_telling]@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
2011-10-24T05:54:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.4ms)
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to [not_telling]@gmail.com (3003ms)
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3137ms
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 heroku[router]: POST swinglx.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3147ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-24T05:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /users] invalidate, pass
```

Any idea what is causing the problem?

Does heroku run in production?

my production URL is SwingLX.com which hasn't registered yet with the DNS name server switch.

Comment: What service are you using to send your email - are you using the sendgrid addon?

Comment: I am not, I will look into that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku does not provide any way of sending email by default - such as local sendmail or similar. Consequently you need to use an external provider such as their SendGrid addon http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid which you would send email through.